How to keep track of selected child items from an array?
New to SwiftData (and Core Data). In my app, I'd like to keep track of a selected item from a list of items, so it's available when the app is relaunched:
@Model
class Person {
    var name: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \ ThingToDo.person)
    var thingsToDo = [ThingToDo]()
    
    var currentThingToDo: ThingToDo? //<---- to keep track of selected ThingToDo
}


@Model
class ThingToDo {
    var person: Person?
    var whatToDo: String
}

When a thing to do is selected from a list, I simply assign it like so:
person.currentThingToDo = selectedThingToDo

This works, but when I delete a to-do item, I get the following message in the console:

CoreData: annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-one
relationship currentThingToDo on object 0x303f273e0...

This is how I'm deleting a ThingToDo item, with the help of this answer:
private func deleteTheThingToDo(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {

    withAnimation {
        
        for index in indexSet {
            let objectId = person.thingsToDo[index].persistentModelID
            let theThingToDo = modelContext.model(for: objectId)
            modelContext.delete(theThingToDo)
            
        }
        person.thingsToDo.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
          
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
    }
}

It appears that I'll get the message in the console above if the item being deleted was referenced by Person.currentThingToDo. Is there a better / simpler way to persist what item was being tracked?

It looks like you deleted the item in the array, but never directly changed currentThingToDo. Wouldn't that make it now point to an object that doesn't exist, hence why things fail when you reference it? What if you set currentThingToDo to nil, first? Also, if you have current... set, and it points to the selected object, do you need to use indexSet at all, or can you use current... to just find the object in the array to begin with?

@LighteningKid, I'm using IndexSet because item being deleted may not necessarily be the item being tracked. I'll try to check first if the item being deleted was also being tracked and set it to nil first. I was wondering if there's a better way to do track this so I can just delete the item without having to check first.

You could trying to set the person property to nil for every ThingToDo object being deleted.
